# custom validation rule for joomla file upload

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to validate a file upload as below using a custom validation rule but its not working.

```
class JFormRuleResume extends JFormRule
{
  public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)
  {
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $fileInput = new JInput($_FILES);
    $file = $fileInput->get('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
    //$files = $jinput->files->get('jform');
    //$file = $files['resume'];

    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['resume']);
    $filesize = $file['size'];

    if (strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename))!='pdf') {
        $element->addAttribute('message', strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename)));
        return false;
    }
    if($filesize<2000000){
        $element->addAttribute('message', "File size bigger than 2MB");
        return false;
    }
    //var_dump($files);
    return true;

  }
}
```

Whether I upload a pdf file or other files with different extension, the error "Invalid file type" is returned.

Please enlighten me what the problem is?

My field looks like this:

```
<field
        name="resume"
        type="file"            
        label="Resume"
        description=""
        size="40"
        accept="application/pdf"
        validate="resume"
        required="true"
    />
```

**UPDATE**

This is an update to what i've discovered so far. The post data

```
$requestData = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'post', 'array');
```

do not fetch the file input value. It is therefore, i've to add the following code in the controller action before i validate the form $data   = $model->validate($form, $requestData);

```
    $requestData = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'post', 'array');
    // Get the file data array from the request.
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $fileInput = new JInput($_FILES);
    $file = $fileInput->get('jform', null, 'files', 'array');

    // Make the file name safe.
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['resume']);
    $requestData['resume'] = strtolower($filename);
    JRequest::setVar('jform', $requestData );

    $form   = $model->getForm();

    if (!$form) {
        JError::raiseError(500, $model->getError());
        return false;
    }

    $data   = $model->validate($form, $requestData);
```

This way i am able to inject the file input value to the post array. But the problem still lies somewhere because the above validation works only partially. The validation works correctly only for files like docx, png, htm, php, txt .... and if i submit doc, pdf (larger than 2MB), zip files the validation do not work at all, instead i am displayed back the form without data and with the validation warning that all the fields are missing.

This is very strange, i desperately need some help.

Comment: Turn on your debugger and tell us what `JFile::getExt($filename)` returns? My guess is, something on the way (i.e. `$filename`, `$file` or `$fileInput`) is not what you expect.

Comment: which debugger do you mean? Joomla debug console is on

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump(JFile::getExt($filename));`? Also, change `!=` to `!==`

Comment: I see nothing returned by var_dump(). I changed it to !== also. Infact when i add required="true" for the field in the form it gives me "Field Required: Resume" and then when i remove it, i get "Invalid Field: Resume" ..... I don't see the custom validation working at all now

Comment: Can you please try adding `var_dump('test');` just before `return true;` and if you don't see anything, I think I might know what the problem is.

Comment: no nothing happens, infact the custom validation has stopped working after i set required="true" for the field. Now i get the error Field Required: Resume ..... The function $model->validate($form, $requestData); in the controller is displaying this error

Comment: without the required="true" attribute and without the custom validation in place i can upload the file also, everything works fine without the validation in place

Comment: In which case your file is not being called at all. Try changing your class name from `JFormRuleResume` to `JFormRuleFile`

Comment: No i don't think so, the problem is $requestData = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'post', 'array'); is not fetching the value from the file input.

Comment: Guys, stop throwing around echos and var_dumps. Use [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/) in conjunction with your favourite IDE. Guessing is sooooo boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made through with the problem of form being redisplayed when file of bigger size is uploaded. It was a server problem, had to change the following in php.ini of my wamp server

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

And regarding the second issue for file upload value not being in post was a new thing to me which i didn't know. Had to upload the file seperately first, then get the name by which the file was saved and then use that name to be inserted in the database.